# Enable cross domain permission in google chrome extension manifest.json

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a simple extension for Chrome. This extension will display a mobile view of the current opened tab of Chrome.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Responsive View",
  "description": "This extension will Display Mobile View Of current opened Tab of Chrome",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"] 
    // what code should be here to grant all permissions for cross domain response?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what code should be here for grant all permission of cross domain response

Corresponding documentation is here: [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

The easiest match pattern to capture all hosts is, literally, `"<all_urls>"`.

If you want to limit this to http/https scheme, you can use `"*://*/*"`

Note that using either of those will create an install-time [permission warning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings):

> **Add "Responsive View"?**
>
> It can:
>
> - Read and modify all your data on all websites you visit